# Use up/down arrows to scroll select list but keep focus on input element

Tags: javascript, jquery, controls

I want user to be able to scroll through select options with up/down arrows, but be able to press ctrl-c to copy from a matching input element whenever they want, seamlessly.

But I'm having trouble juggling the focus.

The best I've gotten is it works but I have to press down twice to move to the next select element.

Here is a fiddle I created, which isn't even populating the select box for some reason. Though it works on my server. On my server the `picsarray` array is generated with PHP, but it should be the same effect as here.

https://jsfiddle.net/bbmqy0xm/2/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can leave focus alone and just call `select()` to highlight the text after you set it:

```
function showpicture(selectobj) {
    /* deleted irrelevant js */
    $("#image_name").val($(selectobj).val()).select();  
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/s4rmytt5/

Comment: Also just one problem: Inside of `showpicture()`, I'm trying to access a property and getting "cannot read property 'undefined' of undefined" error when doing `selectobj.options[selectobj.selectedIndex].value`. Any idea?

Comment: Hey, take a look at this. Although your code works great on the fiddle, it results in the `showpicture` method receiving a jquery "option" in one place, and a regular js "select" element in another. I modified your code to give the regular "select" element and now everything works on my end. Thank you so much!
https://jsfiddle.net/s4rmytt5/1/